# Undefined index, page always redirecting to the same thing

Tags: php, apache, xampp

since I found nothing online regarding my issue here's the deal:

I'm setting 2 variables on my login page:
(login.php)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['active']='1';
$_SESSION['user']=$login;
```

$login is from my post

And I'm using another file to check if the user is logged in some cases:
(session_debug.php):

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['active'] != '1'){
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

The same pages worked on my old server, I've transfered them to my localhost to test some stuff (I'm using apache) and this simply doesn't work.
In my index.php I'm NOT requiring or including the *session_debug.php* but everytime I try to go to *login.php* it just redirects me to index.php, like I was requiring that file on my index, but I'm not...
Heres the error:

```
Undefined index: active in Z:\xampp\htdocs\web\php\session_debug.php on line 3
```

I already tried to make clean installations of xampp and using different versions but, no result.

Looks like its always requiring the *session_debug.php* file even if I don't want it to do so, but I have no idea why or how to do something about it.

Comment: anyone? still didn't figure it out -_-